# 8-bit Line Checksum Calculator for Intel Hex

Tags: python, hex, checksum

I'm trying to come up with a Python solution to get the line checksum for INTEL HEX FILE FORMAT.

```
the_bytes = b'100000000C9425010C944D010C944D010C944D01'


a = b'%02X' % (sum(the_bytes) & 0xFF)

print(int(a))
```

I came up with the bit that calculates the sum of the elements in a line, but I can't get the checksum bit (described there  http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1584/)

For example for a line :

```
100000000C9425010C944D010C944D010C944D0160
```

100000000C9425010C944D010C944D010C944D01 is data

60 is a line checksum.

http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/checksum_converter.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes the hex value as a string, and returns a string with the checksum. Probably not the cleanest way to do it, but returns the same value as the converter you linked:

```
def intel_checksum(value):
  #Remove the : from the beginning of line
  value = value.replace(":","")
  sum = 0
  #Iterate over the bytes in the hex string
  #and add each byte to sum
  for i in range(0,int(len(value)/2)):
      byte = value[i*2:(i*2)+2]
      sum += int("0x" + byte,16)
  #Find the checksum using 2s compliment
  int_checksum = ((sum ^ 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF #https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280234/2393763
  #Return a string, formatted as 2 characters without leading "0x"
  return "{0:0{1}x}".format(int_checksum,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your computation seems to lack the two-complement part, which has to be applied to the computed sum:

```
def twoComplement(n):
    return ((n ^ 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF
```

Further analysis turned out, that sum of a byte string is the root problem because it is quite different from a sum of a bytearray instance or from a sum of bytes: `sum(b'00')` returns 96.

The sum should be applied to the result of `binascii.unhexlify()` of the respective hex digit string.

Comment: After adding two complement it returns 202. So it's not correct as it should be 60 for the example case.

Comment: I know its 60 as this is the checksum of the original line from a file and I confirmed it with tool: http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/checksum_converter.html

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for an SREC, where the first 2 characters are not present "S1" and will generate the checksum for each line. You have to provide the whole SREC as a string:

```
def calculate_checksums(s):
  # Split the string into a list of lines
  lines = s.split('\n')

  # Initialize an empty list to store the modified lines
  modified_lines = []

  # Iterate through the lines
  for line in lines:
    # Initialize the checksum to 0
    checksum = 0

    # Split the line into a list of numbers
    numbers = [line[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(line), 2)]

    # Add each number to the checksum, taking the modulo 256
    # to ensure that the result is always an unsigned 8-bit integer
    for number in numbers:
      checksum = (checksum + int(number, 16)) % 256

    checksum = (~checksum) % 256
    # Convert the checksum to a hexadecimal string and append it to the line
    checksum_str = '{:02X}'.format(checksum)
    
    modified_lines.append(line + checksum_str)

  # Join the modified lines into a single string and return it
  return '\n'.join(modified_lines)
```

To do this for HEX I believe some modification is needed, but for the checksum you should just need to do the 2's complement instead:

```
checksum = ((~checksum) + 1) % 256
```

Example input:

```
1332000103001e0000000a003c0f520314800c
133210681038ff3a0200000000000000000000
13322000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Example output:

```
1332000103001e0000000a003c0f520314800c4E
133210681038ff3a0200000000000000000000BF
133220000000000000000000000000000000009A
```